# Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "config" Use "FLASK_APP=config:name to specify one

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am doing the flask training course [enter link description here](https://habr.com/en/post/346344/)

I'm install Flask-SQLAlchemy in a virtual environment.
I'm install Flask-Migrate:
    pip install flask-migrate

Created a class config.py:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or '*********'    
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')  
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

In models.py I have two models:

```
from datetime import datetime
from app import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {}>'.format(self.username)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post {}>'.format(self.body)
```

In testapp.py only:

```
from app import app
```

In file **init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

from app import routes, models
```

Structure my app:

```
testapp\
  venv\
  app\
    templates\
        base.html
        index.html
        login.html 
    __init__.py
    routes.py
    forms.py
    models.py    
  testapp.py
  config.py
```

In a Python interpreter session, do the following
from app.models import User
and get an error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\testapp>python
Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 
64 bit
(AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> from app.models import User
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "C:\Users\User\testapp\app\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
     from config import Config
   File "C:\Users\User\testapp\config.py", line 8
     SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
                                                                 ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
 >>>
```

Set the environment variable for the new config module
    set FLASK_APP=config.py

When I execute the command:

```
flask db init
```

Complete error log:

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\testapp>flask db init
Usage: flask db init [OPTIONS]

Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "config". Use "FLAS
K_APP=config:name to specify one.

(venv) C:\Users\User\testapp>
```

What am I doing wrong? Help

Comment: can you post the complete error log?

Comment: @Tech at The Sparks Foundation Added full text from console

Comment: Where is your flask application py file?

Comment: It wont compile until you declare your flask application

Comment: @Tech at The Sparks Foundation  I added my question

Comment: First error is the inconsistent tabs error i config.py due to '/' in your code where you are defining sql_database_uri you dont need '/' for defining or condition. Can you try running without this?

Comment: Also can you post your testapp.py in the question

Comment: @  Tech at The Sparks Foundation I removed the '/' character,
but the error is still issued. Added error log and corrected config.py to my question

Comment: Now it's only about inconsistent tabs.. Can you check for indentations?

Comment: @ Tech at The Sparks Foundation Thanks, really indented there was a problem, fixed it. Now another error appears. Added to your question

Comment: I dont think the question is updated

Comment: @ Tech at The Sparks Foundation Updated text after the words: Complete error log.

Comment: Error: Usage: flask db init [OPTIONS]

Error: Failed to find Flask application or factory in module "config". Use "FLAS
K_APP=config:name to specify one.

Comment: Can you post your __init__.py file

Comment: @ Tech at The Sparks Foundation I added the contents of the file __init__.py

Comment: Run this command in cmd `export FLASK_APP=testapp.py` before `flask db init`

Comment: @ Tech at The Sparks Foundation Thanks a lot, it works for me. I have windows and so I ran the set FLASK_APP = testapp.py command, after which the migration repository was successfully created. Thanks again.

Comment: Great I'll post this as answer and you can upvote and accept it so it helps anybody else who visits your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this command in cmd

`export FLASK_APP=testapp.py`

before

`flask db init`